# How to specify another static c library as a dependency/source in rebar?

Tags: erlang, rebar, rebar3

I'm trying to build an application that uses an erlang library. (https://github.com/leo-project/erocksdb). This library itself is a wrapper over a C++ static library (`rocksdb`, compiled as `librocksdb.a`). `rocksdb` is made a git submodule of `erocksdb`, and sits in the `c_src` directory. I'm modifying code in both the places (`rocksdb` and `erocksdb`).

The problem is that if I make a change in one of the `.cc` files of `rocksdb`, the `make` command fired on `erocksdb` only compiles the `librocksdb.a` file (output of the `rocksdb` code), but does not update the `erocksdb.so` file.

This happens because the `rebar.config` does not specify that `librocksdb.a` as a source file. The normal way of adding sources, which is `port_specs` in `rebar.config` cannot be used since it seems to expect the source to be a `C/C++` file, and tries to create a `.o` for each of the source files.

How can I get the dependency reflected correctly?